# scripted shutdown of user level daemons at shutdown

Tags: ubuntu

I'm currently running a few programmes - unreal, anope and the qwebirc web client on startup with crontab.

Anope dosen't take to a non graceful shutdown well, i use flat files for data as opposed to mysql and they corrupt often - i figure if i can get anope shutdown properly via the script it should solve it.

Approaches i suppose might work are using an init script, since crontab dosen't seem to have a @shutdown option, but i'd really like to do shut down apps at shutdown it at as the user i start at.

running ubuntu, but it should be the same on any box running linux

Answer (score 1):

If the daemon doesn't have an init script, you must create your own. Just use an existing script as a template. If you need to execute commands as the user who owns the process, use su or sudo in your init script.

rc0.d is the directory that is processed during a shutdown, be sure to place a symlink to your init script there.

Ubuntu has switched to upstart now, you might also want to take a look at that.